# How To Get Unique Users In Application Insights Monitoring SharePoint Sites?

Tags: sharepoint, azure-application-insights, sharepoint-online

We are monitoring SharePoint Online and SharePoint On-Premises sites using Application Insights.  We can see in Metrics that there is a report showing Unique users.  But the data is anonymised coming from SharePoint Online (i.e. the user_Id is not visible).  So these are hits rather than unique users.

How do we surface unique users from recorded data in Application Insights coming from SharePoint Online and SharePoint On-premises monitored sites?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure firstly the UserId is being captured, can you try to embed the below script in the SharePoint app instead of the snippet you get from the portal.

```html
<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="ScriptLink1" name="SP.js" runat="server" localizable="false" loadafterui="true" /> 
<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="ScriptLink2" name="SP.UserProfiles.js" runat="server" localizable="false" loadafterui="true" /> 

<script type="text/javascript"> 
var personProperties; 

// Ensure that the SP.UserProfiles.js file is loaded before the custom code runs. 
SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getUserProperties, 'SP.UserProfiles.js'); 

function getUserProperties() { 
    // Get the current client context and PeopleManager instance. 
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current(); 
    var peopleManager = new SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager(clientContext); 

    // Get user properties for the target user. 
    // To get the PersonProperties object for the current user, use the 
    // getMyProperties method. 

    personProperties = peopleManager.getMyProperties(); 

    // Load the PersonProperties object and send the request. 
    clientContext.load(personProperties); 
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onRequestSuccess, onRequestFail); 
} 

// This function runs if the executeQueryAsync call succeeds. 
function onRequestSuccess() { 
var appInsights=window.appInsights||function(config){
function s(config){t[config]=function(){var i=arguments;t.queue.push(function(){t[config].apply(t,i)})}}var t={config:config},r=document,f=window,e="script",o=r.createElement(e),i,u;for(o.src=config.url||"//az416426.vo.msecnd.net/scripts/a/ai.0.js",r.getElementsByTagName(e)[0].parentNode.appendChild(o),t.cookie=r.cookie,t.queue=[],i=["Event","Exception","Metric","PageView","Trace"];i.length;)s("track"+i.pop());return config.disableExceptionTracking||(i="onerror",s("_"+i),u=f[i],f[i]=function(config,r,f,e,o){var s=u&&u(config,r,f,e,o);return s!==!0&&t["_"+i](config,r,f,e,o),s}),t
    }({
        instrumentationKey:"XXXX"
    });
    window.appInsights=appInsights;
    appInsights.trackPageView(document.title,window.location.href, {User: personProperties.get_displayName()});
} 

// This function runs if the executeQueryAsync call fails. 
function onRequestFail(sender, args) { 
} 
</script>
```

For additional details please refer to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/sharepoint#capturing-user-id).

Hope the information helps.